# Why is the req.body coming as undefined in my Node.js application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm building a Node.js app and trying to send data from a form using the fetch method. However, when I try to access the data in the req.body object on the server-side, it's coming up as undefined. I've checked that I'm sending the data as JSON using the Content-Type header, and I've also tried using middleware like `body-parser` and `express.json().` What could be causing this issue, and how can I fix it?
Here is the code of client side:

```
    const id = idInput.value;
      fetch('http://localhost:3000/registrar_presenca', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          id: id
        })
      })
```

And here is the code from the server side:

```
app.post('/registrar_presenca', function (req, res) {
  const id = req.id
  console.log('Chamada aberta:', chamadaAberta);
  console.log('Request body:', req.body.id); 
  console.log('ID inserido:', id);
  if (chamadaAberta) {
    if (database.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
      console.log('Aluno registrado: ' + id);
      res.json({ status: 'OK' });
    } else {
      res.status(400).json({ error: 'ID não encontrado' });
    }
  } else {
    res.status(400).json({ error: 'Chamada fechada' });
  }
});
```

Notice that im trying to now the value of 'id', but it is comming as undefined in my console. This is the log of my console:

```
Request body: undefined
ID inserido: undefined
```

Comment: It doesn't say that `req.body` is undefined, it says that `req.body.id` is undefined. If `req.body` were undefined, you would get an error from `req.body.id`.

Comment: Change that to `console.log('Request body:', req.body);`

Comment: console.log(req.body) come as an empty array {}.Request body: {}

Comment: I know you claim to have enabled the json body parser, but I suspect you haven't done it properly.

Comment: how do i do that then?

Comment: Show how you're trying to do it and maybe someone can see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: I've showed, the cliend code is where we send the id to the server, i fetch to 'registrar_presenca' and in 'registrar_presenca', in the server side, i catch the id by cathing the req.body.id, because earlier i sent the id in the body of the requisition.

Comment: I'm talking about the node.js code where you register the middleware. Add that to your question.

Comment: FYI  `express.json([options]` is covered at https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#express.json . Documentation shows three reasons for why the body object may be an empty object (`{}`) which you may wish to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express that can help us parse incoming requests with JSON payloads. It's called express.json() and we just need to add it to our server file using the app.use() method.

```
app.use(express.json())
```

Basically, we can use this middleware function to **Retrieve the JSON data from the request body** and use it to do whatever we need to do in our application.

I hope that adding this code snippet to our server file using express.json() will simplify the process of handling JSON payloads